# Concatenate Base64 String with normal string in Python for JSON

Tags: python, json, base64

I have a requirement of sending images stored in a database on a ubunutu server as binary files using python.

I have managed to successfully convert the file from Binary to Base64 encoded string. However, I am not sure how I can append this encoded string with the default string in Python. e.g.

```
"Text" + ": " + base64.b64encode("text")
```

Any advise or suggestions?

UPDATE:

It produces this error:

> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
>   objects"

Comment: Whats wrong with whats you have?  WFM!

Comment: base64 string are normal strings, when decoding you must pick the correct start char and the end (maybe with padding), you can avoid importing base64 by using 'text'.encode('base64')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json

json.dumps({'image_base64':  
    base64.b64encode(file(image_filename).read())})
```

Don't build json by hand when there are libraries.

Comment: hmm in this case it worked, i guess i am not too fussed about JSON formatting and rendering on a webpage. thanks poolie.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want JSON output, you could just do:

```
return '{"image": "' +base64.b64encode("text") + '"}'
```